# ArcGIS API for Python: SEDF from_layer Fails With 'Layer' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: pandas, spatialdataframe, arcgis-python-api

I'm struggling to build a dataframe out of a featureclass (via a layer), where I'm getting this error message:

```
Exception: Could not load the dataset: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

from this code:

```
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import pandas as pd
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('C:/....../MyProject.aprx'))
project_map = aprx.listMaps("NiftyMap")[0]
lyr = project_map.listLayers("MyLayer")[0]
sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_layer(lyr)


Exception: Could not load the dataset: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

I can't see what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The wrong `GeoAccessor` method is being called to load the data set.  From [GeoAccessor - ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#geoaccessor):

> *static* `from_layer`(layer)¶
>
> ```
> The from_layer method imports a FeatureLayer to a Spatially Enabled DataFrame
> ```

The `from_layer` method wants a data set, specifically a **FeatureLayer**.  What is being passed in the current code is an ArcPy Mapping Layer (`arcpy.mp.Layer`), which isn't a data set but an object holding a reference to a data set.  If the data set referenced in the ArcPy layer is a FeatureLayer, then the current code works; however, if the data set referenced in the ArcPy layer is a feature class, then the code needs to be changed:

```py
from arcgis.features import GeoAccessor, GeoSeriesAccessor
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import pandas as pd
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('C:/....../MyProject.aprx'))
project_map = aprx.listMaps("NiftyMap")[0]
lyr = project_map.listLayers("MyLayer")[0]
sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_featureclass(lyr)
```